# Sql query containing 2 databases

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, ms-access

In C# I want to execute a query that use 2 different databases (One is Access for local, and other is distant and is MySQL)

I'm able to do it in VBA Access, but how I can make the same thing in C# ??

This is how I made it in Access:

Link my 2 differents table/databases in Table

In VBA:

```
sSQL = "INSERT INTO DB1tblClient SELECT * FROM DB2tblClient"  
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL
```

How I can execute this SQL in C# ? (What object to use, etc... Example code if you can)

Thanks !

Comment: you need to specify database name as such : dbname.dbo.tablename

Comment: What object / connection I need to make that ?

Comment: Are you executing that SQL against the Access database? Which of those tables is in the MySQL database?

Comment: DB1tblClient is Access and DB2tblClient is MySQL. This code is already working in Access. I want to make the same thing in C# Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the same SQL command from any app, really.  This is assuming:

- You're connecting to Access from your C# app
- `DB1tblClient` is a local Access table
- `DB2tblClient` is a link table in Access

Given these, you might try the following:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Stuff\MyAccessdb.mdb"))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DB1tblClient SELECT * FROM DB2tblClient";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You might want to check [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) if you can't get the connection string right, and you may need to install some components (MDAC or ACE) for connections that use those providers.

Comment: Thanks for your code !!!, In Access it work like that right now... But if I want to not use Access to have the linked table in it but just use C# ? lol It amazes me that we can't make it directly in C# ! I will probably use this method if this can't work in C#...

Comment: We cannot add data source in our project, or something like that (datareader, dataset, datatable, etc..) to make this SQL working ?

Comment: @user2072536 I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I just asking if we can use data source to link database/table like in Access (newbie question lol). And after use this data source to execute the query.

Comment: But I made it with your method and it's working ! Thanks ! I'm just amaze that we can't do that directly in C# ;) Thanks all again !

Comment: It looks like @Dan has offered one possibility and others have mentioned alternatives, though the code would be much more complex (and require more testing than just using Access' well-tested methods for doing this).

Comment: I mean link 2 databases/tables (like in Access) and after execute directly the SQL whitout making datatable, looping on each records, etc... ;) This is newbie databases programming in C# ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.  One is to set up linked tables on Access and run a single query.  The other is to run both queries from c# and join them with linq.

The first way is better.  If you really have to do it with linq, here is some sample code:

```
dWConnection.Open();
dWDataAdaptor.SelectCommand = dWCommand1;
dWDataAdaptor.Fill(queryResults1);
dWDataAdaptor.SelectCommand = dWCommand2;
dWDataAdaptor.Fill(queryResults2);
dWConnection.Close();

IEnumerable<DataRow> results1 = (from events in queryResults1.AsEnumerable()
                       where events.Field<string>("event_code").ToString() == "A01"
                       ||  events.Field<string>("event_code").ToString() == "ST"
                       select events ) as IEnumerable<DataRow>;


var results2 = from events1 in queryResults1.AsEnumerable()
    join events2 in queryResults2.AsEnumerable()
    on (string)events1["event_code"] equals (string)events2["event_code"]

    select new
            {
                  f1 = (string)events1["event_code"],
                  f2 = (string)events2["event_name"]
            };

DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable();
newDataTable = results1.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

See why I said linked tables is better?

Comment: loll Thanks ! I'm new in C# and I don't even think it was so difficult to make a simple query like sSQL = "INSERT INTO DB1tblClient SELECT * FROM DB2tblClient" in C# ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well it is not possible to run this such complex query with single statement.

Basically each query execution object initialized by particular database information,
so need two different object for each database **first think**.

Now 2 Object need with initialized with its own connection object.

Just fetch data by first object and insert it to another database by usin second connection object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep following points in mind before trying this type of query

1. Both the databases are accessible from your code.
2. There is inter-connectivity between both the database.
3. Both the databases are available for the user that you are using to execute this query.
4. You need to specify the query in following format

`DATABASE_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME` instead of just `TABLE_NAME`

**EDIT**

If you don't have inter-connectivity between databases you can follow following steps

1. Connect to Source database using one `connection`.
2. Read the data from source database into a `dataset` or `datatable` using `SELECT` query.
3. Connect to target database using a second `connection`.
4. Insert all the records one by one using a loop to TARGET Database using standard `INSERT` query

Comment: Ok. Yes, Both table/databases are accessible.  This is some technician on the road that need to update his table(Access) from MySQL. This work already in Access VBA like I said. But I want to eliminate Access and make this software in C#. Thanks!!

Comment: Right Now, I'm able to open 2 connections (I use OleDbConnection and OdbcConnection) coon.Open(); and oleConn.open(); work.. Now I dont' known whic object to use or whaterver thingto do to execute this SQL. If you are able, can you show me a little piece of code after my connection object is open to execute this query ? Thanks!

Comment: is there inter-connectivity between both the database?

Comment: no, I want just to take data from one table(DB1) and put it in second table (DB2). One is local(Access DB1) on few laptop. This persons need to update their database (DB1 Access) with data on MySQL (DB2) at distance (work on the road). Thanks !

Comment: Your "Database_name.Schema_name.table_name" seem great to me...How to code that in C# ? I mean,  I probably need to open connection/link someting for Database_name.Schema_name.table_name being accessible in the query...(I mean need of datareader, new data source, dataadapter ??)

Comment: This query will be executed only if there is inter-connectivity between both the databases. Else you need 2 connections (one for each database). One connection will read the records from database. Other will insert all the records into target database.

Comment: i have edited my answer, that may help you to prepare a simple C# code. You can easily find codes for using select and insert statements for various databases.